# Python class static/instance defaults

Tags: python, oop, programming-languages

This is actually two questions:

1) What is that logic behind the fact that, when declaring a python class, do variables default to static and methods default to instance? I know i can declare variables in _*init _* or add @staticmethod or @classmethod to methods to flip them to the other side, but it just seems (to me at least) having them both consistently default one way or another (e.g. like Java/C#) would make much more sense.

Is there some very common use case i am missing? I  know the implementation is as such, but surely it must have been a design decision to have it this way, having methods default to instance but having variables default to exactly the opposite.

2) Is there any way to declare instance variables in python classes without putting them in _*init _*?

I know i can put them in _*init _*, but that would require any subclasses which need their own _*init _* to either:

A) declare them himself or

B) manually call the base classes _*init _*  themselves,

both of which are a pain. I could do it, but it feels dirty; subclasses something should require nothing more than the (BaseClass) in the class declaration to work, they should not need to call anything special in their own _*init _* for the BaseClass functionality to work fully

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're up against is related to the way that things are processed / evaluated as the modules are read in.

```
class Parent(object):
  someAttr = Parser() # Static variable - created as the class is parsed.

  def __init__(self):
    self.otherAttr = Reader() # Instance - created when the class is instantiated.

class Child(Parent): pass
```

Child will have the static `someAttr` and also the instance `otherAttr` because it did not override the `__init__` method from the Parent.  You don't have to have each child class create the same instance variables if it does not require special `__init__` handling.  It will automatically call the Parent's `__init__` if it hasn't provided one of its own.  Hopefully that clarifies some.

Comment: Yep, but the problem is i cannot guarantee that my children do not need special __init __ handling; I suppose i could (because i am writing them) but it just seems dirty to be forced to put a Parent.__init __(self) at the head of every sub class.

Comment: @Li I think I'm confused by your expectations ... either they do need special handling, and you write separate `__init__` functions for them, they don't, and you let the Parent class handle it, or they need both the parent handling and specialized handling, in which case you call `Parent.__init__(self)` first and then add extra instantiation steps afterward.

Comment: I was just hoping for some way of doing it without having to put the Parent.__ init __ (self) inside. I _can_ do it, but it makes my library more complex to use: you have to remember to always add the Parent.__ init __ (self) to the top of any __ init __ function you define. I want it to be like in Java: you extend the class, and you automatically get all the instance methods and instance variables, nothing else needs to be done. I know it's just a single line of code, but one redundant line (redundant because i'm never going to _not_ have it) is one redundant line too many =)

Comment: @Li: Just a suggestion, but if when you do need to include the call to a superclass's `__init__`, you'd be better off using `super(Child, self).__init__([args, if any])` or, in Python 3, `super().__init__([args, if any])`. And it's not dirty if you only make the `super().__init__()` call at the start of any subclasses. Even Java requires you to explicitly put a call to a superclass constructor if you need one with arguments.

Answer (score 2):

1) Python's approach for implementing classes is very different from languages like Java and C#. It's very flexible, and you can override and modify almost every part of its behaviour, you actually have control over the implementation of how they work.

Class attributes are just objects that live in the namespace of the class. The object themselves define the behaviour during access from the instance or the class, this happens through the so-called descriptor protocol. Objects that do not implement the descriptor protocol act like what you call "static" objects (e.g. read-only access from the class and the instance is the same). Objects such as functions, classmethod objects, properties implement this protocol.

You don't need to know the details, but it's the object that defines the behaviour:

- Functions want to act like methods
- Properties want to let you define how the attribute acts
- Static methods remove any custom behaviour (staticmethod objects simply wrap the function object and disable the descriptor protocol; they can wrap any object)

2) You should always call the `__init__` of the superclass (as opposed to the parent class). This is commonly done using `super(CurrentClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`